# What’s a good frontend for python that’s not too difficult to learn

Tags: python

I’m currently in high school and have around 6 to 7 months to make an app, Im fairly good with python and was looking for a decent front end language/ library to use for my app, I wanted it to be modern and since we have the time me and my team are able to learn 1 or 2 new languages which we intended to do so either way. I looked all over the web for a decent solution and the two most common solutions to a modern looking UI seem to be Eel and React. However I’m unsure as to which is better at handling python code and also not too complicated for an intermediate level student. I realise python has libraries like tkinter and kivy too but I’m told they aren’t as good and also I was looking forward to learning how 2 or more languages can be used to develop an app.

If it helps answer the question, the app will most probably be handling things like convolutional neural networks or recurrent neural networks along with some other stuff like scrapers and openCV

Answer (score 2):

One GUI framework is wxPython.  It is derived from wxWidget, which is the same for C++, so there are already two languages.  It is kept up (the last update was 2020-11-21) and complete with good documentation.  I have used this and it's been pretty easy for me.

A second GUI framework is QT.  It, too, is kept up (last update: 2021-08-18) and is also complete with good documentation.  QT also has frameworks for other languages.

Both are also cross-platform.